# Find closest next hour in array of hours

Tags: php, arrays, time

I want to find next closest hour in an array of hours, I have below code which searches for closest hour in both directions after and before.

what i need to do is to search only next hour which in below example should be 14:00 instead of 03:50.

Details about conditions:

- Duration: 24H - 1D
- Start Hour: 00:00
- Values both in $timeslots and $expected_time are dynamic

```
$timeslots = ["01:00","01:30","02:00","02:30","00:30","01:00","01:30","02:00","02:30","03:50", "14:00"];
$expected_time = "04:00";
$timestamp = strtotime($expected_time);
$diff = null;
$index = null;
        foreach ($timeslots as $key => $time) {
            $currDiff = abs($timestamp - strtotime($time));
           if (is_null($diff) || $currDiff < $diff) {
                $index = $key;
                $diff = $currDiff;
            }
        }
echo $timeslots[$index];
```

Comment: You want to find what? Based on what parameters? Could you provide some more examples?

Comment: It's not clear 1) why $timeslots array is not sorted; 2) why anyone attempts to calculate the modular difference between two times if the nearest _next_ slot should be taken anyway.

Comment: You don't specify what closest means for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code seems correct. It does not return the **next** hour because you're using the absolute value of the time difference for comparison, instead, do this:

```
$timeslots = ["01:00","01:30","02:00","02:30","00:30","01:00","01:30","02:00","02:30","03:50", "14:00"];

$expected_time = "04:00";
$timestamp = strtotime($expected_time);
$diff = null;
$index = null;

foreach ($timeslots as $key => $time) {
    
    // Don't use abs function here - to get negative values as well
    $currDiff = $timestamp - strtotime($time);

    // Add a condition to check if the difference was negative or not - because it'll only be the "next" hour when the difference is negative
    if ((is_null($diff) || abs($currDiff) < $diff) && $currDiff < 0) {
        $index = $key;
        $diff = abs($currDiff);
    }
}

if(!is_null($index))
    echo $timeslots[$index];
else
    echo 'Not found';
```

Comment: Doesn't find a value for `18:00`

Comment: @Tajni Yeah it won't, because there IS no timeslot greater than 18:00 in the OPs array. Why is that an issue?

Comment: Next one is `00:30`. Question is incorrect, because it mixes closest with next time.

Comment: It's subjective whether the next one is `00:30` depending on whether you are considering only the current day or not; OP does not mention `date`. Only mentions time. So in that respect, it works correctly.

Comment: And what's the problem if 'it mixes closest with next time"? OP wants the "next closest time". What's the problem in that and how does that make the question incorrect? It doesn't.

Comment: I'd say this does not work. You might as well just use end($arr). https://3v4l.org/NeOTE

Comment: I didn't say your answer is incorrect but you showed that you don't understand the issue. Why you didn't return `3:50`? It's the next closest hour tho.

Comment: You can say my answer is wrong. No problem. It's not about that. You've not even read the question it seems. **It's not returning `03:50` because the OP wants the NEXT CLOSEST hour, not the PREVIOUS closest hour**. You've posted about 5-10 comments and also deleted your own answer and all your comments are inaccurate. What's the problem?

Comment: @Andreas but if you use `end($arr)`, it'll not return the **closest** next hour. It'll just return the last value in the array. Right?

Comment: And that is what your code does too. Look at the link

Comment: All is correct, 00:30 is previous time in perspective of single day (It might be my issue not mentioning the date factor and thinking it would be clear in my comment "should be 14:00 instead of 03:50." but as it seems nvkrj understood exactly what i needed ) ,  @nvkrj , the code is exactly what i needed and thanks for explaining the issue in the comments

Comment: @nvkrj looks like Andreas point is legit. not sure how to fix it thought

Comment: @Andreas I think it must be a bug in my code. Why don't you try to post the correct version of it in your own answer? I also want to know how it will work

Comment: @Andreas yes please kindly post your version please.

Comment: There is still unclear parts of the question. What if there is no "14:00" what is the "correct" answer? "Nothing found" or should it expect first possibly time in the array as if that is tomorrows date?

Comment: @Andreas can't you just assume that the OP want's today's time if they've not mentioned a date anywhere in the question? Won't that be a vaild assumption to make, at least until the OP explicitly requests you to give the next day's time slot?

Comment: I don't assume when I answer.

Comment: For example, consider a scenario where the script wants to calculate if there is any open time slot today after the given time or not. In that case, if say the time entered is `20:00`, then the script returns "Not Found". Isn't that a possible scenario?

Comment: @Andreas it is single date, in case of 14:00 answer should be "not found".

Comment: Thank you! @BofficeGeo be right back with an answer

Comment: @Andreas and BofficeGeo this does give "Not Found" in case of "14:00" https://3v4l.org/u8rKu .. then what is the problem with it?

Comment: @BofficeGeo I've fixed the bug in the code above to get the right results.. It was in comparing a negative value with another negative value.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to sort an array before we start iterating it.

Then once we find a matching item in the array we break the looping and output what we find

```
$timeslots = ["01:00","01:30","02:00","02:30","00:30","01:00","01:30","02:00","02:30","03:50", "14:00", "15:00", "15:30"];
sort($timeslots); // first we sort the array, very important

$expected_time = "04:00";
$timestamp = strtotime($expected_time);
$diff = PHP_INT_MAX;
$index = null;

foreach ($timeslots as $key => $time) {
    
    $currDiff = $timestamp - strtotime($time);

    // Add a condition to check if the difference was negative or not - because it'll only be the "next" hour when the difference is negative
    if ($currDiff < $diff && $currDiff < 0) {
        $index = $key;
        $diff = $currDiff;
        break;
    }
}

if(!is_null($index))
    echo $timeslots[$index];
else
    echo 'Not found';
```

https://3v4l.org/kGdP8

Comment: can you please explain how this gives a different result than my code above? https://3v4l.org/EQ6h1

Comment: In that specific scenario there is no difference. But when you have more times after 14:00 then it works differently

Comment: Ah I got it now - you added another element to the hours array `15:30` and that's when it starts giving incorrect results. And this is happening because the negatives are comparing in reverse.. so `currDiff` is ALWAYS lesser than $diff.

Comment: I've fixed it in my answer now..

Comment: Although that is an assumption that the array may be different and that the input may be different. It's a healthy way of assuming

Comment: My assumption was also healthy wasn't it? To me, it's almost obvious that the OP wants the timeslots in the same day - and it turned out to be right as well.

Comment: @Andreas sorry for late reaction, I left office and just arrived home. and you are correct about your assumption, values both in array and expected_time will change (Will try to spend more time on details in case of future topics). thanks a lot for pointing out the issue in nvkrj -s code and fixing it. I am so grateful for both of you and confused on marking correct response.